# Bootstrap push down column

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

How can I accomplish for Bootstrap to push a column on next line if doesn't fit? This is a link how it is right now: [Link to current page](http://drivprojekt.se/medarbetare/)

Image of current page:

[image]

This is an image how it is right now. I'd like that the third image to drop to the row below if it doesn't fit.

This is code below

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
        if($members):
    ?>
    <ul class="team_members">        
        <li>
            <?php foreach($members as $member): ?>
            <div class="cl col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <?php if($member["member_avatar"]): ?>
                <div class="animated">
                    <div class="member drivprojekt" style="border-radius: 50%; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
                        <img src="<?php echo $member["member_avatar"]["sizes"]["member_thumb"]; ?>" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="cl col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="member_info">
                    <h3><?php echo $member["member_name"]; ?></h3>
                    <h4><?php echo $member["member_position"]; ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo do_shortcode(nl2br($member["member_description"])); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use bootstrap grid and group the image with the text.
And why using an ul tag for only one li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `flex-box`

```
ul.team_members li{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Tried to upvote your answer but my reputation is too low. :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use this kind of divs if you want. Its just a suggestion

```
<div class="cl col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-3"></div>
```

replace col-md-3 to col-md-2